# (Python Gtk) Update ListBox Content

Tags: python, listbox, gtk

I am trying to dynamically add an element to a ListBox.
It works without a function but not with.

**Works**

```py
rootbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=10)

button = Gtk.Button(label="ok")
listbox = Gtk.ListBox()

el = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
label = Gtk.Label('Element 0')
el.add(label)
listbox.add(el)

button.connect("clicked", addList)

rootbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)
rootbox.pack_start(listbox, True, True, 0)

window.add(rootbox)
```

**Does not work (it prints 'ok' but doesn't add the element)**

```py
# -------------------
def addList(b):
    print('ok')
    global listbox
    el = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
    label = Gtk.Label('Element 0')
    listbox.add(el)
# -------------------

rootbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=10)

button = Gtk.Button(label="ok")
listbox = Gtk.ListBox()

button.connect("clicked", addList)

rootbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)
rootbox.pack_start(listbox, True, True, 0)

window.add(rootbox)

# -------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`window.show_all()` needed at the end of the *addList* function ! Hope it helps